USB-C Sound Interface disconnects when Macbook Pro M3 sleeps and does not recover
When my 16" Macbook Pro M3 (November, 2023) goes to sleep, my Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 sound interface disconnects and I have to re-plug the USB-C cable back to get it working again.
It is plugged in directly into a USB-C port, not via a USB hub.
Is there a way to sleep the Macbook Pro without cutting power to the USB-C port? I would expect it to power back on after sleep mode.
Running macOS Sonoma version 14.3.
